# Is it OK to have a single front chainring paired with 7 speed at the back?

Tags: gears, cassette, derailleur-rear

I'm planning to have a single front chain ring to be paired with my 7 speed at the back. I'm still saving up for a 10 speed.

Comment: Fine in what way? Is it physically possible? Will it make a good bike? (We don't know -- it depends what you want to do with it) Is it cost-effective? (You'll have to buy _two_ dereailleurs and cassettes.) Something else?

Comment: Get a 21-speed bike and remove two of the front rings.  Done.

Comment: So, your plan is 1x10, not 1x7? If yes, I'd better leave the bike as it is till you have all the components you need. I think there's no reason to implement a part of your plan

Comment: Maybe we should have a minimum question length?  This one seems to assume a lot.  Short questions beget short answers.

Answer (score 1):

Without taking into account whether it's a good idea or not; yes it's possible, with a few caveats.

You have two issues:

**Chain line** i.e., alignment between the front rings and rear cassette.

The single ring needs to be aligned with the center of the cassette so you minimize the lateral deflection on the chain and avoid excessive wear on the chain and sprockets.

With a 7 speed rear its likely that you have a triple set of rings. If so just us the middle position for the single front ring as it's aligned with the middle of the cassette. If you have a double, things are trickier but you may be able mount the ring on the inboard side of the spider.

**Dropping the chain**

The front derailleur helps to keep the chain on the front rings. Outer rings help keep the chain on inner rings. With an unaided single front ring there is a greater chance of dropping the chain from it.

1x11 setups feature a *narrow-wide* chainring that have alternating narrow and wide teeth that fit between the inner and outer chain connecting plates to more firmly hold on to the chain. If you are looking to do this conversion as cheaply as possible you probably don't want to get a new chainring. Leave the front derailleur in place to act as a chainguide.

You don't say whether you are saving for a whole 1x11 bike, or or planning to replace the drivetrain on you current bike. In either case [this article](https://dirtmountainbike.com/bike-reviews/brakes-gears/1-x-11-cheap.html) may be of use to you. If the latter, bear in mind you will need to check compatibility between your freehub body and an 11 speed cassette.

Answer (score 1):

I converted my '96 Gary Fisher Alfresco to a budget 1x7. I simply removed the front derailer, kept the original Sugino chain rings and a Shimano hyperglide 7 speed cassette.

The only problem is that my chain falls off the chainring frequently. The front derailleur helps to keep your chain on the chainrings. There are chain guards available that help to keep the chain on the chainrings.

The chainrings on a 3x or 2x group set are designed to allow a chain to move off the chainring while shifting, but a 1x chain ring is designed to hold on to the chain.

If you go the 1x route, be sure to get a 1x chain ring. It sounds like this is your plan.

Comment: If you left the big chainring on, then it will be out of line for the lower gears.  Try and move it more centrally, which might mean flipping it, moving to the other side of the spider if possible, or changing the chainring bolts to allow more movement.

Answer (score 0):

Sure 1x is fine.   Cannot get a narrow wide chain ring in 7 speed but it should still be OK.

Comment: Surely this depends on the use? Might be OK for general road use, but without a narrow-wide chainring or a clutched rear mech there is a high chance that the chain could jump off the the chainring if you took it off road, especially if you are in the smaller cogs.

Comment: @Drew How much off roading do you do in smaller cogs?

Comment: When descending on my Enduro bike I'm fairly often at the smaller end of the cassette. We don't have detailed information from OP on his bike and what his intentions are with it, so it may be that he has an old triple MTB that he takes down some gnarly descents...

Comment: Tons of kids mountain bikes comes with 1x and have 5,6, or 7 gears in the back with a [crankset like this](https://gzmyu4ma9b-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Cleary-Kids-Cranks.jpg).  I've also seen adult bike with similar cranksets. The chain should stay on reasonably well even with moderate offroad use.

Comment: I understand you guys saying it's depending on use, and your what if's are useful, but the simplicity of it is, the OP didn't give us that, and simply asked if it's ok to have one gear in front and 7 in back.  And the answer is yes.  Why this is getting downvoted is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

1x7 is totally fine. Just remember to get *narrow wide* chain rings and also get a chain guide if possible. Oh yes, and lastly cut short your chain enough for the tension to be high.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It’s fine !! I have mine with a Single chainring and a 7 Speed Cassette and has been riding like crazy for several weeks and the Chain does not fall off! There will be rubbing of chain against the smaller Gears which is not in alignment!

Comment: Why is the chain rubbing?  What is your chainline like?  While you say it works, this doesn't make it sound very practical.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely,  it's like having a triple with a broken cable. Keep the derailleur on if you can.